# Is there a way to get the Pylint exit code when running from Python (instead of CLI)

Tags: python, pylint

When running Pylint from the CLI, I can get the exit code with `echo $?`

However, I am running Pylint from Python using the epylint module (as described in the [documentation](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html)). Unfortunately, the docs do not describe how to get the exit code when running from Python. Is there a way to do this?

For reference, this is how I'm currently running the linter:

```
from pylint import epylint as lint

pylint_options = 'foo -E'

(pylint_stdout, pylint_stderr) = lint.py_run(pylint_options, return_std=True)

print('StdOut:')
print(pylint_stdout.getvalue())
print('StdErr:')
print(pylint_stderr.getvalue())
```

Comment: I've never used this module, so I am reluctant to reply.  However, nobody else has offered any suggestions so I'll take a stab.  It is possible there is no exit code.  The "pylint" command might just invoke py_run() (in process) and then look at the output and from that determine an exit code.  You are assuming that py_run() forks a new process . . . do you know for sure that is even the case?

Comment: @Frank Merrow: I don't know whether py_run forks a process. So I'll look into how pylint infers the exit code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`epylint.py` has a `lint` function you can call instead of `py_run` where `lint` returns the exit code.

```
def lint(filename, options=()):
```